# Flutter: How can I remove shared_preferences from the app?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I have several warnings caused by shared_preferences plugin. It is not in my pubspec.yaml, but is installed by default. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: Is `shared_preferences` a dependency of another package? You can see the dependency tree by running `flutter pub deps`

Comment: Yes, of flutter_session. Thank you, this helps!